# Permission error while developing Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress plugin development & I want to make a plugin. So far I managed to add Menu in Dashboard. Now I want to add a submenu. Menu works when I click on it but submenu doesn't work. It shows this error, `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` My code is below,

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sms_dashmenu');

function sms_dashmenu() {

    add_menu_page( 'sms_menu_page', 'SMS Demo','manage_options', __FILE__,'sms_plugin',plugins_url( '/Images/logo.png', __FILE__ ) );
    add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'AdminPanel','Admin', 'manage_options',__FILE__.'/menu1', sms_panel_admin);
}
function sms_plugin(){
    echo 'Welcome to the business!';
}

function sms_panel_admin(){
?>

<h2>Admin Panel Design</h2>

<?php
}
?>
```

Is there something wrong in my code? I need a solution badly. Your help would be appreciated. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter in `add_menu_page` is the menu slug of string type use anything unique you want, and the first parameter of `add_submenu_page` is the parent slug and that is what you entered for add_menu_page menu slug

```
add_menu_page( 'sms_menu_page', 'SMS Demo','manage_options', 'smsmenu','sms_plugin',plugins_url( '/Images/logo.png', __FILE__ ) );
add_submenu_page( 'smsmenu', 'AdminPanel','Admin', 'manage_options', 'smsadmin', 'sms_panel_admin');
```

Check [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

Comment: Tnx a lot. This wordked perfectly. :)

Comment: If its not trouble for u, can u give me your fb id or any other so that I can discuss with u about wordpress since i see u have good knowledge in wordpress? :)

Comment: yes ofc. But I never chatted here before so don't know. Can u invite me?